# Как отсортировать записи по среднему рейтингу в сложном запросе?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть таблица адресов

```
Address  model:

belongs_to :service
belongs_to :district
has_many :providers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :jobs, through: :providers
```

К каждому адресу есть комментарии(отзывы) с полем stars(оценка).
В модели адресов сделал метод:

```
Address.rb

    def self.find_by_test(params)
    addresses =  Address.where(services:{active: true}).joins(:service).joins(:district => :city).joins(:district).joins(:jobs).includes(:addresses_car_models, :car_models).joins(:comments)

    addresses  = addresses.where(:cities => { :id => params[:city_id] }) if params[:city_id]
    addresses  = addresses.where(:districts => { :slug => params[:district_slug] }) if params[:district_slug]
    addresses  = addresses.where(:jobs => { :slug => params[:job_slug]}) if params[:job_slug]
    addresses  = addresses.where(:car_models => { :slug => params[:car_model] }) if params[:car_model]

    addresses_with_rating = []

    addresses  = addresses.distinct

    addresses.map.with_index do |addr,i|
      rating = addresses.select('comments.stars').where(comments:{confirmed: true, address_id: addr.id}).distinct.average('comments.stars')
      rating = 0.0 unless rating
      provider = addr.providers.joins(:job).where(:jobs => {:slug => params[:job_slug]}).first if params[:job_slug]
      last_record = addr.comments.where(address_id: addr.id).order(:updated_at => :asc).last
      last_record = (last_record || addr).updated_at
      comments_count = addr.comments.count
      addresses_with_rating[i] =  {location: addr.location, latitude: addr.latitude, longitude: addr.longitude, days: addr.days, start_time: addr.start_time, end_time: addr.end_time, around_the_clock: addr.around_the_clock, id: addr.id, rating: rating.to_f, online: addr.service.online, name: addr.service.name, service_id: addr.service.id, phone: addr.phone, avatar: addr.service.avatar, description: addr.service.description,  comments_count: comments_count, slug: addr.service.slug, provider:provider, last_subscribed: last_record}
    end
    addresses_with_rating = addresses_with_rating.sort_by { |k| k[:rating]}.reverse
    if params[:start] && params[:finish]
      addresses_with_rating = addresses_with_rating[params[:start]..params[:finish]]
    else
      addresses_with_rating
    end
  end
```

В контроллере вызываю его так:

```
@results = Address.find_by_test({
    :city_id => params[:city].id,
    :district_slug => params[:district],
    :job_slug => params[:id],
    :car_model => params[:model]
  })
@services_count = @results.length
@results = @results[0..1]
```

Так же есть метод:

```
def take
@comments_count = Array.new
@results = Address.find_by_test({
    :city_id => params[:city].id,
    :district_slug => params[:district],
    :job_slug => params[:id],
    :car_model => params[:model],
    :start => params[:start].to_i,
    :finish => params[:finish].to_i
  })
 cookies[:start] = cookies[:start].to_i + 2
 cookies[:finish] = cookies[:finish].to_i + 2
end
```

который я вызываю в take.js.erb

```
$(".search_results").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list') %>");
$(".search_results").append("<%= escape_javascript link_to "Показать еще", list_path(:start => cookies[:start], finish: cookies[:finish]), :remote => true, class: 'btn btn-success more' %>");
```

Очевидно при хоть сколько-то большом количестве записей и пользователей это будет давать сильную нагрузку на сервер. Как обойтись без массива, чтобы была возможность отсортировать адреса по среднему рейтингу в коммнтариях? Решения с will_paginate не подходят, т.к. этот гем конфликтует с другими в проекте.

Comment: Написать подсчёт рейтинга в SQL-запросе разве что.

Comment: вот я  и не понимаю как его написать, чтобы в запросе в котором находятся N адресов, каждому подсчитать рейтинг в одном sql запросе, на ум только цикл  и приходит

Comment: Посмотрел, как составляется `addresses`... Не берусь предполагать, сколько SQL это генерирует само по себе, туда прицепляются практически все ассоциации, причём вразнобой... Вы делаете поиск на манер тех, что встречаются в интернет-магазинах? Такое обычно решают отдельным поисковым решением вроде Sphinx или ElasticSearch. Это так, к сведению. Средствами БД, уверен, тоже можно, но стоит ли? .-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конечном итоге было сделано так: в таблицу address добавил поле с рейтингом, при подтверждении модератором отзыва собираются рейтинги из подходящих отзывов и  значение записывается в новое поле. В таком случае сложный запрос не нужен.